# .htaccess allow with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to allow video access to

```
www.mysite.com/root/video/sample.mp4?token=122892
```

I deny other route such as wrong token or no query token access

```
www.mysite.com/root/video/sample.mp4
www.mysite.com/roote/video/sample.mp4?token=wrongtoken
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^token=122892$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking condition for default variable `QUERY_STRING` if its not matching `token=122892`(value provided by OP) then forbid that page.