# Apache htaccess allow/deny with query string doesn't show files in folder

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988771/19419156) for allow access to the folder if there's a token parameter with the value '123'. I don't have html or php files in my folder, there are only mp3 files. If I go directly to a file, it works, but if I go to the folder it shows an empty list of the files.

[Picture of the empty list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f27RD.jpg)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What directives are you currently using? The contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Guess: You will probably need to activate the `ShowForbidden` IndexOption. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions